# Search LastName and FirstName in AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to retrieve the first name and last name of the user that is logged in his/her machine using AD. I use the following code:

```
string server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.Server"];

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + server);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

User user = GetUser(entry);

searcher.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" + user.UserAD;
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

private static User GetUser(DirectoryEntry userEntry)
{
    Usuario user = new User();
    string[] username = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].Split('\\');

    //THIS IS WHAT I NEED BUT IT DOES RETURN null.
    //User.Name= (string)userEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value;
    //User.LastName= (string)userEntry.Properties["sn"].Value;

    user.Domain = username[0];
    user.UserAD = username[1];

    return user;
}
```

Now, I know `searcher.PropertiesToLoad` have a `[memberof]` and `[adspath]`, the last one gives me the first and last name separated with a comma, something like `CN="gates, billy"` but I dont want to use substrings and index, is there any property like `[firstName]`, `[lastName]` in the list properties?

I did search that `DirectoryEntry` have a property called `givenName` and `sn` but this returns `null`

Answer (score 1):

The `PropertiesToLoad` set is exactly what you need to modify. Active Directory will return only the properties which are defined in this set, that's why you don't see `givenName` and `sn`. Just add these properties as well:

```
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
```

Alternatively, just add the property `*` to load all of them:

```
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("*");
```